# Visual Studios code, virtual environment issues

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I recently downloaded vscode to start some small python projects for myself, however I keep running into the same error(seen below) while trying to create the virtual environment which is essential for python extensions. I've tried pasting the error into google and have found nothing. I was hoping someone might be able to explain the issue. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: try to change the path of your project OneDrive sometimes give an error if your offline or no internet connection 
hope helpful for you

Comment: there is a BIG named in the error message, did you have a look there, if if does not work in Powershell (who uses that) try `cmd.exe`

Comment: Please paste the error message, not the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the command "`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process`" in the VS Code terminal to temporarily change the PowerShell execution policy to allow the script to run, please refer to: [virtual environments in VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments)

In addition, if it still doesn't work, please use it as mentioned in the comments in "settings.json":

```
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
```

Reference: [Can I use Cmder's shell with the terminal on Windows?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, only python 3.3 or higher support for virtualenv.
If you use python 3.3 or higher, you can search and run PowerShell as administrator, change directory to Activate.ps1 file and run it, it may fix your problem